# Can we retrieve data back from Google Drive API in Android?

Tags: android, android-studio, google-drive-android-api, google-drive-realtime-api

I'm able to successfully add my images to google drive, using the API provided by Google Drive.

Can I now retrieve it back to my App?
If yes, Can anyone help with how to do that?

Comment: Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36154369/how-to-get-images-from-google-drive-into-android-application) that may help you.

Answer (score 0):

Use this to retrieve files from the Google Drive API

`https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/[FILEID]?key=[YOUR_API_KEY]'`

If you want the entirety of code required to retrieve a file, here it is:

```
import com.google.api.client.http.GenericUrl;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpResponse;
import com.google.api.services.drive.Drive;
import com.google.api.services.drive.model.File;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

// ...

public class MyClass {

  // ...

  /**
   * Print a file's metadata.
   *
   * @param service Drive API service instance.
   * @param fileId ID of the file to print metadata for.
   */
  private static void printFile(Drive service, String fileId) {

    try {
      File file = service.files().get(fileId).execute();

      System.out.println("Title: " + file.getTitle());
      System.out.println("Description: " + file.getDescription());
      System.out.println("MIME type: " + file.getMimeType());
    } catch (IOException e) {
      System.out.println("An error occurred: " + e);
    }
  }

  /**
   * Download a file's content.
   *
   * @param service Drive API service instance.
   * @param file Drive File instance.
   * @return InputStream containing the file's content if successful,
   *         {@code null} otherwise.
   */
  private static InputStream downloadFile(Drive service, File file) {
    if (file.getDownloadUrl() != null && file.getDownloadUrl().length() > 0) {
      try {
        HttpResponse resp =
            service.getRequestFactory().buildGetRequest(new GenericUrl(file.getDownloadUrl()))
                .execute();
        return resp.getContent();
      } catch (IOException e) {
        // An error occurred.
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
      }
    } else {
      // The file doesn't have any content stored on Drive.
      return null;
    }
  }

  // ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks Aayush, Where do i write/implement this?

Comment: Add the methods to the activity class where you are doing all the API work, and add all the import statements. Make sure you customize the variables for the code to be compatible with yours.

Comment: Please accept my answer if it worked or tell me if it did not.

Comment: do i have to add any dependency for the imports?

Comment: No, no dependacy needed.

Comment: i am not able to understand, the proper way of implementing this!!
Where do i call printFile(service, id) method?

Comment: The method returns the files resource. Call it where you want the file. For more help, consult google's [documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/files/get#examples)

Comment: What is a fileID? (Sorry for taking to much of your time)

Comment: Click with the right mouse button on the file that you want to download in your Google Drive. Choose the option to get a link which can be shared from the menu. You will see the file id now.

Comment: This is the only process to get  a file. You now need to find a way to get file id of a file from Google drive API. That is a different question that can be answered with a different question.